# Canopen node become stuck in preop state

Tags: embedded, communication, can-bus, canopen

I have 2 nodes (x and y) on a can bus using canopen. Using a temp node "z" I send an nmt message to put all nodes in preop state and then a command to put y into operational state. I then send a bunch of extended id messages on the bus intended for node y, node x does not know of these in its  dictionary. During the sending to y, node monitoring on node x says it is in preop state. All seems fine. Upon completing of sending  data to node y I send a command to put all nodes into operational state. Node x is stuck in preop state according to its nmt state code. Debugging i found the rx fifo in canopen x is overflowing. It should be ignoring all these extended messages when in preop mode? I even tried in stopped mode with the same results of a stuck x. Whats going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any CAN bus node, you have to read all incoming messages continuously and ignore the ones of no interest. Filter settings in the CAN controller can help a bit, but to build rugged applications, you must always be prepared that any CAN message with any ID can appear at any time. The best way to ensure this is to always read rx fifo buffer continuously, and at each time keep reading until it is empty.

A CANopen node remains in pre-operational state as long as there are errors. Optionally, it may send out an EMCY message telling the nature of the error, and then another with all bits set to zero when the error is cleared. In which case the NMT master should wait until EMCY clear message, before sending out start remote node.

Comment: Thanks Lundin. I was under the assumption in canopen NMT states such as preop or stopped automatically ignore all messages except for other messages which the state allows i.e. preop ignores PDOs, is that incorrect? In any case I am processing all can messages via an interrupt so the buffer should never be full... I'm not seeing any EMCY messages... maybe I have some other issue going on outside the stack. If there is an error sent out over EMCY is the only way to clear it by sending an NMT message such as go to reset communication?

Comment: @Michael Rx FIFO overflow is on a lower level than CANopen, somewhere between the CAN driver and the CANopen stack. Perhaps in the stack adaption to a certain controller. The CANopen stack should indeed ignore PDOs in pre-operational mode, but that's on the application level. EMCY messages are, as I said, optional. But they can help control flow if you expect certain errors. Errors should be cleared in a way that makes sense. If you have an internal error in a node, no other node can clear it, but the error needs to be dealt with.

Comment: It turns out that the provided CANopen driver for STM32 assumes that any extended id messages are filtered out via hardware filter. This caused my extended ID message to be read as an uninitialized standard ID message, which is of ID = 0 aka an NMT message. This caused the unusual behavior. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @Michael Ok that's weird. I hear bad things about ST's CAN drivers overall. Lots of bugs apparently.